# SQL Moving Aggregation

Tags: sql, query-optimization, common-table-expression, window-functions

Issue:  For a given recordset containing a date column, an arbitrary number of category columns, and a value column, I would like to compute aggregations of value for an arbitrary date window, such as 30 days, 365 days, etc.  I have looked at the window aggregate functions, CTEs, and a few others but they do not appear (to me at least) to perform the desired function.

The SQL (T-SQL) below typifies the basic idea what I a trying to accomplish, but I have a bad feeling about its scalability, particularly the join, and the increased difficultly once I try grouping by other nominal groups.

```
    SELECT 
        basedate
        , count(*) as [n]
        , sum(Value) as [SumValue]
        , avg(value) As [AverageValue]
        , stdev(value) As [StdevValue]
FROM
    (SELECT t1.basedate , t2.*
     FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT dt as basedate from foo)as t1
         ,foo as t2
      WHERE datediff(d, t1.basedate, t2.dt) between -30 and 0
      ) t3
GROUP BY t3.basedate
ORDER BY t3.BASEDATE DESC
```

I created a SQLFiddle to try to make it more concrete.

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/414ed/1)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using SQL-Server 2008 as your fiddle suggests?

Comment: I am using SQL-Server 2008 currently, but this could be a Teradata query down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing around a bit with the setup provided in the SqlFiddle I came to these two potential solutions: (well, the first one is only half of the solution, not sure how I would add stdev() on there in an efficient way)

```
WITH t1
  AS (SELECT DISTINCT dt as basedate from foo),
     sumcount
  AS (SELECT basedate,
             SUM((CASE WHEN datediff(d, t1.basedate, t2.dt) between -30 and 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as [n],
             SUM((CASE WHEN datediff(d, t1.basedate, t2.dt) between -30 and 0 THEN value ELSE 0 END)) as [Sumvalue]
        FROM t1, foo t2
       GROUP BY basedate)
SELECT basedate,
       [n],
       [Sumvalue],
       [Sumvalue] / [n] as [Averagevalue]
  FROM sumcount
ORDER BY basedate DESC


GO

WITH t1
  AS (SELECT DISTINCT dt as basedate from foo),
     t2
  AS (SELECT basedate, min_date = DateAdd(day, -30, basedate), max_date = DateAdd(day, 0, basedate) from t1)

SELECT basedate,
          count(*) as [n]
        , sum(b.value) as [Sumvalue]
        , avg(b.value) As [Averagevalue]
        , stdev(b.value) As [Stdevvalue]
FROM  t2 
JOIN  foo b
   ON b.dt BETWEEN t2.min_date AND t2.max_date
GROUP BY basedate
ORDER BY basedate DESC
```

I prefer the last one for it's simple readability, and coincidently it runs quite a bit faster too although I can't quite tell why yet. Mind that I loaded the test-data a 100 times extra (using the magic of GO 100) to get some longer durations out of it on my laptop. (it's hard to compare 1ms vs 1ms =)

[image: Query Plan Explorer Screenshot]

**Surprisingly**, **the (accepted) solution** from Halt CO **returns different results** than the original query (or 'my' queries) when given the 'extended' test-set; you might want to look into that! (The reason being that it finds the base-dates multiple times, sums mulitple times due to this and then in the end ends up with much bigger Counts and SumValues. I'm not sure this is what you want, or if it is something that might happen with 'real data', but since you put an index and not a UNIQUE index on that foo table I'm assuming doubles can occur... )

Answer (score 0):

In my brief testing this is faster than your current query if the `dt` field is indexed:

```
SELECT    a.dt AS basedate
        , count(*) as [n]
        , sum(b.Value) as [SumValue]
        , avg(b.value) As [AverageValue]
        , stdev(b.value) As [StdevValue]
FROM  foo a
JOIN  foo b
   ON b.dt BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-30,a.dt) AND a.dt
GROUP BY a.dt
ORDER BY a.dt DESC
```

Edit:  I asked about version because in SQL Server 2012+ there's support for `RANGE`/`ROWS` which can create a moving window like you're going for, I believe you're stuck with a self-join.  Using `DATEADD()` and comparing the `dt` values is marginally faster than your `DATEDIFF()` version.

Comment: I added the index and tested locally. The original solution: 1108ms CPU, 179ms elapsed.  The proposed solution: 1841 ms CPU, 512 ms elapsed.  the IO on the original solution foo table: scan count 12, logical read 178, worktable scan count 8, logical reads 66862,  proposed solution: foo scan count 10 , logical reads 31, worktable scan count 836 logical reads 244163.  Any thoughts on the more scalable solution given the io results?

Comment: @user3092841 Was the original query already cached? The reason for the increased performance that I saw was that I got an index seek instead of an index scan thanks to using `dt` in the comparison instead of `DATEDIFF()`, but either way you lose some benefit since you need a range.

Comment: I updated the SQL Fiddle [link] (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba2f4/4) the plans are nearly the same.  [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba2f4/4/0) VS [link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ba2f4/4/1) I very much appreciate your help on this, I thought perhaps there was an order of magnitude type solution out there, but it seems not.

Comment: @user3092841 Yeah the sql fiddle plan was about the same from what I saw, I only saw the difference in the more detailed plan shown on my sql server instance.  Can't think of any other big improvements offhand.